# ListView is not view on SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My ListView in unable to get showed on SwipeRefreshLayout in Android.

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The XML Screen is BLANK as nothing is showing.I have not written any code for the java file .

Comment: The list view has no content, so nothing will show

Comment: Thanks ,But Its not giving any hint that the ListView has been successfully dropped on the SwipeRefreshLayout that is  in the design section i.e  XML screen ,Prior running the emulator. Please help..!!

Comment: It wont, until you provide the listview with an adapter that contains data to display in the listview

Answer (score 0):

If you want data to be prepopulated and just show the hard coded data you can use
e.g.

> android:entries="@array/countries"

```
  <string-array name="countries">
        <item> India</item>
        <item> USA</item>
        <item> Germany</item>
 </string-array>
```

If not you will have to write java code and once the app is launched then only the data will show up on the emulator screen. Layout Editor just reads through your layout files.